# rollup-plugin-vue v4.6.2 has a problem with vue-runtime-helpers

Tags: vue.js

The latest (as of writing) version of rollup-plugin-vue is 4.6.2

It has a dependency on vue-runtime-helpers version 1.0.0

This version has an error. When trying to create a bundle with Rollup, it produces the error

> Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/vue-runtime-helpers/dist/normalize-component.js

Prior to this, rollup-plugin-vue version 4.6.1 with vue-runtime-helpers version 0.2.0 works fine.

Comment: I just started experimenting with rollup in my Vue project, and ran into the same issue. The feedback I get is nonsensical and pinpoints the erroneous line of code to a random line in my vue file. Had a quick glance at the related packages, but couldn't immediately find anything damning.

Comment: Also having this issue in my library. Not finding any helpful info. Build does not complete.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer to this in their [latest commit](https://github.com/vuejs/rollup-plugin-vue/commit/fd3dfb9a4440b13b220fb2dc535506274280fa0c), you must also include [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs) in your `rollup.config.js`:

```
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
    entry: 'index.js',
    plugins: [
        commonjs(),
        vue(),
    ]
}
```

This should stop the error from occurring.

Comment: Thanks for the update M. A.! I can confirm that this solves the problem.